# How to get my custom URL to the URL browser when Search Data

Tags: php

I think from the title its not really clear so I'm goning to explain it here, I got an URL like this => localhost/restoq/?page=Laporan, but when I tried to search it with my query its only show localhost/restoq/?search=example. So what I need to do to get the "?page=Laporan into my URL?

Form :

```
<form action="" method="GET">
      <div class="form-row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="">Keyword</label>
                <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Keyword" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['search'])) { echo $_GET['search']; } ?>"  />
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row mt-3 float-right">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Search</button>
       </div> </form>
```

Query :

```
if(isset($_GET['search']) ) {
    $keyword = $_GET['search'];
    $query = "SELECT barang.kode, barang.nota, barang.tgl_input, barang.no_inv, barang.status_doc, barang.posisi_doc, barang.no_po, barang.nilai, users.nama FROM barang INNER JOIN users ON barang.id_user = users.id_user 
    WHERE barang.nota like '%".$keyword."%'
    OR tgl_input like '%".$keyword."%'
    OR status_doc like '%".$keyword."%'
    OR posisi_doc like '%".$keyword."%'
    OR no_inv like '%".$keyword."%'
    OR no_po like '%".$keyword."%'
    OR nilai like '%".$keyword."%'
    ORDER BY barang.kode ASC";
} else {
    $query = "SELECT barang.kode, barang.nota, barang.tgl_input, barang.no_inv, barang.status_doc, barang.posisi_doc, barang.no_po, barang.nilai, users.nama FROM barang INNER JOIN users ON barang.id_user = users.id_user ORDER BY barang.kode ASC";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the form tag to something like:

```
<form action="?search=<?php print $_GET['search']; ?>" method="GET">
```

Full example:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (!empty($_GET['reset'])) {
    header('Location: /index.php');
    exit();
}

function search(string $string) 
{
    return [
        'result1',
        'result2',
        'result3',
    ];
}

function real_escape_string($value)
{
    $search = array("\\",  "\x00", "\n",  "\r",  "'",  '"', "\x1a");
    $replace = array("\\\\","\\0","\\n", "\\r", "\'", '\"', "\\Z");
    return str_replace($search, $replace, $value);
}

$results = [];
if (!empty($_GET['search'])) {
    $results = search(real_escape_string($_GET['search']));
}

?>

<form action="?search=<?php print $_GET['search']; ?>" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="search" value="<?php !empty($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : ''; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

<?php
if ($results) {
?>
    <h2>Results</h2>
    <div class="results">
<?php
    foreach ($results as $result) print '<br>' . $result;
?>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The query parameter will be overwritten after submission, you'll want `<input type="hidden" name="search" etc..`

Comment: I was doubting myself after your comment, so I did try this out. Indeed when `method="GET"`, `?search=` does get wiped out after submitting the form.

Browsers resolve the path and overwrite all query parameters when `method` is set to `GET`.

Comment: Works for me... I updated my answer with the full example.

Comment: Yes obviously your example works because you are respecifying `search` again as an `input` field. You can remove it from the `action=`, attribute, as that one does get ignored (which was the point of my comment). You do have a bunch of XSS bugs here though, and you shouldn't invent your own escaping mechanism.